# Where is the audio/video sources information stored in xbian?

Tags: kodi, xbian

Where is the information for the audio/video sources stored?

I know in the xbmc GUI you can add sources, but they use the IP address (e.g. `192.168.1.2`). This works out great until the address changes. Then I have to remove and re-add it back with the new address.

I am able to resolve the same host using the `hostname.local` convention, and I would like to use this for my sources as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sources are stored in

```
~/.xbmc/userdata/sources.xml
```

I found this out through their code posted on github. Specifically [this snippet parsing through the sources file](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/14689e236b72348cae153b0fb755a0aae500ea0b/tools/darwin/runtime/preflight#L48), and from [this snippet showing the folder](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/14689e236b72348cae153b0fb755a0aae500ea0b/tools/darwin/runtime/preflight#L19).

I have setup the host that serves the content as a static local IP through my router, while I find a more universal solution.